# Microsoft Word/Excel equivalent to the "Search the Menus" functionality of Google Docs/Sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, google-spreadsheets, microsoft-office-2016, google-docs

In Google Docs/Sheets, I can hit `Alt-/` (`M-/` for Emacs users :) ) to bring up a menu that allows me to quickly search all the menus for a particular function and to select that function with `[Enter]` (e.g. bold, create bulleted list, change font size). This is particularly helpful because it allows me to continue typing without switching to the mouse. Is there an equivalent function within Microsoft Office 2016/Word/Excel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the most recent version of Word and Excel 2016, Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to put focus in the 'Tell Me' search field on the ribbon. You can then type to describe what you're trying to accomplish -- for example, **Bold**, **Bullet**, or **Font**.

[image: Tell Me field]

If the item you want is at the top of the list of returned results, you can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply it. Otherwise, you can then press <kbd>Down arrow</kbd> to move focus into the list of results and go through the list of options, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply the correct one. If one of the options has a submenu, press <kbd>Right arrow</kbd> to expand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the "Insert Function" button on the Formula Bar in Excel:

[image]

Windows: <kbd>SHIFT+F3</kbd>

Mac: <kbd>Fn + UP + F3</kbd>